# selenium webdriver Findelement confused

Tags: selenium, find, element, phantomjs

I have looked around forum and haven't find right answer for my misunderstanding.

Let's say we have html code:

```
<h3 id="param_search_0" class="mygray open" data-searchparam="any42" data-id="0">Text here</h3>
```

So if I get element by tag "h3" like this:

```
IWebElement get_element = Element_from_above.FindElement(By.Tag("h3"));
```

What element will I get (select for later use), just text? If yes so how can I select full line element, or seperate, text and inside parameters, from `<h3></h3>` loop.

Thank you and sorry for this maybe stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Giving you an answer in Java, as you have not specified the language that you're using:**

Suppose that you've created a web-driver instance:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

First, you need to access the web-page in which you are interested, using the URL of that web-page:

```
driver.get(url);
```

Then, you can either get **the first `<h3>` element** in the web-page:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("h3"));
```

Or you can get a list of **all the `<h3>` elements** in the web-page:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("h3"));
```

Then, you can get various attributes of that element.

**For example, in order to get "the entire line" as you call it:**

```
String line = element.getAttribute("outerHTML");
```

**For example, in order to get "just the text" as you call it:**

```
String line = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

And in a similar manner, you can get the value of each and every attribute within the element...

Comment: oh, ok I'am trying it. My code first takes block off html, thant loops to seperate <h3> tags, but i need that atributes.

Comment: I'am using C#. But this one is same.

Comment: No problem; Answer slightly revised in order to provide a bit more information...

Comment: I was confused about element selection, but looks like all selectors takes full HTML, not only text :) Very happy with this, because debugging in visual studio there is no information about inner, outer HTML, on IWebElement. Thanks one more time.

Comment: Yeah, NP... the "innerHTML" and "outerHTML" attributes are not specified anywhere within the API for some reason.

Comment: @barakmanos: To get the text of an element, why can't we use `getText()` rather than `element.getAttribute("innerHTML")`?